# Task Scheduler starts multiple times

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks

So I've set up a `Task Scheduler` which should run every 20min but for some odd reason, it looks like it starts, and then try to start it again a couple of times? Have I set it up wrong?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Replace "for a dutation of:" from "indefinitely" to "1 day".

Comment: Why should I do that?

Answer (score 0):

To build on [timetosail](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13532785/timetosail)'s answer, which worked for me today...

You need to either set the task to run `One Time` with the duration of `Indefinitely`, or `Daily` with the duration of `1 day`.

Using both `Daily` and `Indefinitely` adds a new run at 4:01:23pm (and another every 20min after that) without stopping the "every 20min" runs scheduled yesterday (or any day before that).

(Mine was attempting to launch between 5 and 25 times every 20 minutes.)